# WPF "Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, так как этот файл используется другим процессом."

Tags: c#, wpf, исключения

Возникла проблема, возникает exception при попытке удаления файла "файл используется другим процессом". Программа следующая, через FolderBrowserDialog выгружаю картинки на ListBox(имя и путь картинки храню в list'е), при нажатии delete из контекстного меню картинка должна удалиться как на форме, так и в самой директории. 
Код следующий:

```
public static List<image_class> image_details = new List<image_class>();

    private void BtnOpen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        using (FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog()) {
            if (fbd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {
                foreach (string item in Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath)) {
                    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(item);
                    if (fileInfo.Extension == ".png" || fileInfo.Extension == ".jpg" || fileInfo.Extension == ".txt") {
                        image_details.Add(new image_class { name = fileInfo.Name, location = fileInfo.FullName });
                        listBox.ItemsSource = image_details;
                        listBox.Items.Refresh();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        var path = image_details[listBox.SelectedIndex].location;
        if (listBox.SelectedIndex != -1) {
            var result = System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Delete image named: " + image_details[listBox.SelectedIndex].name + " ?", "Confirm delete", MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
            if (MessageBoxResult.Yes == result) {
                File.Delete(image_details[listBox.SelectedIndex].location);
                image_details.RemoveAt(listBox.SelectedIndex);
                listBox.Items.Refresh();
            }
            else {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Select an image to remove.", "Warning");
            }
        }
    }
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Строка `var path = image_details[listBox.SelectedIndex].location;` должна идти после `if (listBox.SelectedIndex != -1) `, и вообще она там лишняя, удалите ее.

Comment: И `File.Delete(..)` разумнее делать после `listBox.Items.Refresh();`

Comment: Файл удерживается где-то в другом месте. Это же пути к картинкам? Вы эти картинки как-то используете? Покажите, как именно. И покажите ваш `image_class`.

Comment: Вангую: читается путь из image_details и открывается файл через класс Image, но, ошибка у автора скорее всего связана со строкой var path.. он же не привел целиком выхлоп ошибки.

Comment: image_class представляет собой два поля типа string - name и location. var path - осталась от предыдущих тестов, в коде, что опубликован здесь она никак не используется, не обращайте внимание на нее.
Сам exception: 
System.IO.IOException: "Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу "E:\test folder\m3.jpg", так как этот файл используется другим процессом."

Comment: В приведенном коде нет ничего, использующего файл. Так что ищите в других местах, где вы открываете (и удерживаете) файл. Наверняка NewView прав - вы где-то используете `Image`/`Bitmap`.